# How to use Spring DSL in Groovy to inject dependency based on environment (dev, qa, prod)?

Tags: spring, grails, groovy, dependency-injection, dsl

We've built a web app in Grails/Groovy. In groovy, we built a pluggable caching component to provide caching of large http response streams in the Grails app. We want to inject the cache implementation at runtime based on environment, for example, when a developer is doing some local work, inject a simple Map-based cache, but in an operational environment, inject a RDBMS cache database, you get the point.

We found this reference in the Grails tutorial which uses SWITCH, and it seems to work, but it's ugly and cumbersome. We've got over 5 different environments (local, dev, test, uat, and prod) and we need to inject environment-specific classes elsewhere in our code, so this approach is definitely not ideal. Are there any alternatives? Examples would be appreciated, thank you!

```
//from resources.groovy
beans = {
    switch(Environment.current) {

    case Environment.PRODUCTION:
        cacheBean(com.util.OracleCacheImpl) {
           //properties here            
        }
        break

    case Environment.LOCAL:
        cacheBean(com.util.MockMapCache) { 
           //properties 
        } 
        break 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try setting your bean definitions in `Config.groovy`, using its built in `environments {}` handling, and assigning the definitions via the `application` property.

So in `resources.groovy`:

```
beans = {
    // Create a clone of the properties definition Closure
    def cacheProps = application.config.cache.bean.props.clone()
    cacheProps.delegate = this
    cacheBean(application.config.cache.bean.class, cacheProps)
}
```

And in `Config.groovy`:

```
environments {
    production {
        cache.bean.class = com.util.OracleCacheImpl
        cache.bean.props = {
            //properties as in resources.groovy
        }
    }
    'local' {
        cache.bean.class = com.util.MockMapCache
        cache.bean.props = {
            //properties as in resources.groovy
        }
    }
    'uat' {
        //etc...
    }
    //etc...
}
```

Thinking a little longer on it, you could probably put the whole bean definition in a `Config.groovy` `Closure` and call it in resources.groovy

`resources.groovy`

```
beans = {
    // Create a clone of the properties definition Closure
    def cacheBeans = application.config.cache.beans.clone()
    cacheBeans.delegate = this
    cacheBeans()
}
```

`Config.groovy`

```
environments {
    production {
        cache.beans = {
            cacheBean(com.util.OracleCacheImpl) {
                //properties here            
            }
        }
    }
    'local' {
        cache.beans = {
            cacheBean(com.util.MockMapCache) {
                //properties here            
            }
        }
    }
    'uat' {
        //etc...
    }
    //etc...
}
```

Comment: I think resources.groovy directly supports the same per-environment configuration as Config.groovy, though this is really isn't a big improvement on using a switch statement.

Comment: If it does, then I just learned something new. :-) Otherwise, I was just throwing out an idea for him.

Comment: This is more or less the same as SWITCH, am I missing something?

Comment: Yes, it is the same as switch, it just allows you to centralize any environment-based configuration in Config.groovy, since you mentioned in your post you had other environment-based configurations you had to set.  Unless I misunderstood you and the other environment-based setup you mentioned is in resources.groovy as well, then this answer doesn't help you much.

Comment: @RaffiM I think we're all missing something, what exactly is the problem with the switch statement approach?

Comment: @schmolly, on second thought, this is a reasonable solution because it does allow centralization of all environment-specific configuration in one place, thanks